# This is a cron-job in node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to make a cron-job that runs a function after 24 hours but if it's a friday, then the timer should stop at 23:59 and restart on sunday at 23:59. How do I do this?

Imagine a request being created. When this is created, an email function has to be called. If a reply for the said email is not received within 24 hrs, the email function should be called again and the 24 hrs timer should start again to repeat this process for a third time. But if it is a saturday and the timer is running, it should stop and then restart back on monday. (This is to indicate that no time from saturday or sunday has been consumed in the timer).

Comment: The easiest way? Make your function return immediately if the day of the week is Saturday or Sunday. J

Comment: Checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron you can wrap your function inside the callback or even if you wish to have your cron functionality in a different file you can fork it as a callback for cron schedule then by catching error of process or even fork process on('exit') you can signal the end of process and log anything as you need as a success.

Comment: Thank you for your help fellow devs.  @O. Jones this seems easy but the function should also restart on Sunday at 23:59.

Answer (score 0):

Some cron patterns allow you to specify day ranges (e.g. `59 23 * * 1-5` runs only Monday to Friday).

Fore more complicated logic, setting the cron to run everyday + inspecting the day of the week in your application might be simpler like O. Jones commented.

Personally, I'd lean towards the latter so you can log when the cron ran and skipped because it was a weekend, so you have a record, if things ever go wrong or you need to debug something.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is to run the function everyday at 23:59 from monday to friday right? I need it for a specific case. Imagine a request being created. When this is created, an email function has to be called. If a reply for the said email is not received within 24 hrs, the email function should be called again and the 24 hrs timer should start again to repeat this process for a third time. But if it is a saturday and the timer is running, it should stop and then restart back on monday. (This is to indicate that no time from saturday or sunday has been consumed in the timer).